# I can't create a custom title: "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: titles, memoir, pdfx

I need to generate a pdf compliant with `PDF/X-1a:2001` and I'm having an error trying to create a title page based on [`titleTH`](http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf#section.A.2).

I'm having the error:

> Undefined control sequence. \titleTH

When I click into the error message, I go to this line of `pdf.sty` file:

```
                           % 2010 for PDF/A-2, 2012 for PDF/A-3.
```

Why my code is not working?

### Code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents} %if filecontents should overwrite old files
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{My Title}
    \Author{My Name}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4} file{ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
    /OutputIntents [ <<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S/GTS_PDFX
    /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (ISO Coated v2 300 (ECI))
    /Info(ISO Coated v2 300 (ECI))
    /RegistryName (http://www.color.org/)
    >> ]
}
\pdfinfo{% not needed with newer PDF/X versions
    /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001)%
    /GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)%
}
% -------------------------------------------------------Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleTH}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \begingroup% TH Typography
    \raggedleft
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    {\Large The Author}\\[0.167\textheight]
    {\bfseries The Big Book of}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\textcolor{red}{\Huge CONUNDRUMS}}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\small With 123 illustrations}\par
    \vfill
    {\Large The Publisher \plogo}\par
    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
    \endgroup}


\begin{document}

    \mainmatter
    
    \titleTH
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just guessing:  `\plogo` seems to be undefined

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes, it was just that. Thanks!

Comment: don't rely on your editor to know what is wrong, look in the log-file.

Comment: do you use texstudio? (that is well known for scambling the undefined command error message unfortunately)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for that, checking the log the error is described very well: *`! Undefined control sequence.
\titleTH ...r \vfill {\Large The Publisher \plogo ...`* I'm new using LaTeX. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I'm using TeXStudio.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the link. In fact, something strange was happening in my original document: when I clicked on the error message it sent me to a meta property of the PDF that I had not defined, to test I defined that meta property, compiled again and the error message sent me to the next property that was not defined. I thought it was not possible that it would force me to define all the meta properties ... I'm happy with TeXStudio, but it's a shame it didn't fix this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.